# how to get next/prev row from mysql by group

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table on MySQL like this:

```
ID    Name    Group
1     One      A
2     Two      B
3     Three    A
4     Fore     C
5     Five     B
6     Six      A
7     Seven    B
```

I want to get the previous row/ next row in same group from my selected row. Like if I have selected row with ID=5, now how can I get the same group previous row(ID=2) when I haven't any information about the row and same with next row(ID=7).

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query ... and be aware that group is a reserved word in MySQL, and ill-suited as a table /column identifier

Comment: What's your expect result?

Comment: @D-Shih I am just showing results from table by group, and I want to create next/pre button, so when user stay on row(id=1) then next button carry the row(id=3) data because it in gorup a.

Comment: @Hobo I answered a question you can try it.

Comment: I am working with this

Comment: @Hobo you can upvote or mark the answer if that help you:)

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [LEAD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lead) or [LAG](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lag) with `Windows function`, but it's was supported mysql higher version than 8.0. so you can instead write a subquery on `select`

look like this.

**TestDLL**

```
CREATE TABLE T(
   ID int,
   Name VARCHAR(100),
   `Group` VARCHAR(5)
);

INSERT INTO T VALUES (1,'One','A');
INSERT INTO T VALUES (2,'Two','B');
INSERT INTO T VALUES (3,'Three','A');
INSERT INTO T VALUES (4,'Fore','C');
INSERT INTO T VALUES (5,'Five','B');
INSERT INTO T VALUES (6,'Six','A');
INSERT INTO T VALUES (7,'Seven','B');
```

**Query**

```
select *,IFNULL((
          SELECT t2.ID
          FROM T t2 
          WHERE t1.Group = t2.Group and t1.ID > t2.ID 
          ORDER BY t2.ID DESC
          LIMIT 1
         ),t1.ID)previousID
         ,IFNULL((
          SELECT t2.ID
          FROM T t2 
          WHERE t1.Group = t2.Group and t1.ID < t2.ID 
          ORDER BY t2.ID 
          LIMIT 1
         ),t1.ID) nextID
from T t1
```

**[Results]**:

```
| ID |  Name | Group | previousID | nextID |
|----|-------|-------|------------|--------|
|  1 |   One |     A |          1 |      3 |
|  2 |   Two |     B |          2 |      5 |
|  3 | Three |     A |          1 |      6 |
|  4 |  Fore |     C |          4 |      4 |
|  5 |  Five |     B |          2 |      7 |
|  6 |   Six |     A |          3 |      6 |
|  7 | Seven |     B |          5 |      7 |
```

If your mysql support windows function, you can try this.

```
select *,
  LAG(ID)previousID,
  LEAD(ID) nextID
from T
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a9d4e/21)